# How to Make My VB.NET Web Apps Work On Android

Tags: android, vb.net

Lets Say ,I have VB.NET website.I want this application to also work on Android. Will I have to start building that android app from scratch or i can shift to android by Using existing Code. What steps do i needs for that .I am new to android.

Comment: You can just navigate to your website on the android web browser

Comment: if there any alignment or design issues on your website in android device to convert your web apps to the html5 support!

Comment: @Longball27 ..if There Are some Media stuff in .NET application how to make compatible with Android?